Why Destructor is called so many times in the for loop? What object is it destructing?
I'm just starting my C++ journey (learning since March) and I really do not understand the behavior I'm getting from code similar to the following:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Testing{
    
    private:
        bool    object_alive;
        int     object_id;

    public:
        Testing(bool alive, int id);
        ~Testing();
        bool check_if_alive();
        void unalive();
};

Testing::Testing(bool alive, int id) : object_alive{alive}, object_id{id} {
    cout << "\nCONstructor on object: " << object_id << endl;
}
Testing::~Testing(){
    unalive();
    cout << "\nDEstructor on object: " << object_id << endl;
}

bool Testing::check_if_alive(){
    return object_alive;
}

void Testing::unalive(){
    object_alive = false;
    cout << "\nObject " << object_id << " under testing is dying!" << endl;
}

vector<Testing>* gather_objects_under_testing(int amount_of_objects);

int main() {
    vector<Testing>* gas_chamber{gather_objects_under_testing(2)};
    int number_of_objects_alive{0};

    Testing* object_in_front{nullptr};
    object_in_front = &(*gas_chamber).at((gas_chamber->size())-1);

    do{
        number_of_objects_alive = 0;
        object_in_front->unalive();
        object_in_front -= 1;
        for(auto &object: *gas_chamber){
            if(object.check_if_alive())
                ++number_of_objects_alive;
        }
    } while(number_of_objects_alive > 0);

    return 0;
}

vector<Testing>* gather_objects_under_testing(int amount_of_objects){
    vector<Testing>* chamber = new vector<Testing>;
    for(int i{amount_of_objects}; i > 0; --i){
        (*chamber).push_back(Testing(true, i));
    }
    
    return chamber;
}

The output I'm getting is this:
CONstructor on object: 2

Object 2 under testing is dying!

DEstructor on object: 2

CONstructor on object: 1

Object 2 under testing is dying!

DEstructor on object: 2

Object 1 under testing is dying!

DEstructor on object: 1

Object 1 under testing is dying!

Object 2 under testing is dying!

Why is the destructor called so many times in the for loop? What objects is it affecting?
As you can see from this:
Testing::~Testing(){
    unalive();
    cout << "\nDEstructor on object: " << object_id << endl;
}
void Testing::unalive(){
    object_alive = false;
    cout << "\nObject " << object_id << " under testing is dying!" << endl;
}

The object stored in the vector should have its attribute changed when the destructor is called, but this is not what's happening - it's affecting some copy I'm not aware of.
Should I use some different kind of (de)reference or pointer when doing for loops? Just like I'm doing in this part, using ampersand:
for(auto &object: *gas_chamber){
    if(object.check_if_alive())
        ++number_of_objects_alive;
}

I'd like to know what exactly is happening in the for loop in this function that is causing the destructor to be called so many times, and how to make this better so no objects are created and destroyed multiple times over when this function is called.
vector<Testing>* gather_objects_under_testing(int amount_of_objects){
    vector<Testing>* chamber = new vector<Testing>;
    for(int i{amount_of_objects}; i > 0; --i){
        (*chamber).push_back(Testing(true, i));
    }
    
    return chamber;
}


Try adding logging for the copy constructor and move constructor.

Side note : vector<Testing>* no you don't need the pointer here.  So get that out of your system first. As a rule of thumb, if you're new to C++ don't use new/delete. Have you read std::vector's documentation yet?  Pay attention to iterator invalidation/resizing (which kind of means you cannot loop over a vector safely and add or delete elements from within the loop)

vector<Testing>* gather_objects_under_testing can just return a std::vector<Testing> don't worry no unecessary copies will be made. C++ has something called RVO/Copy Elision to avoid making copies of objects on returning from a function.

What object is it destructing? -- cout << "\nObject " << object_id << " under testing is dying!" << endl; -- Instead of outputting just a message and your "object_id", you should also be outputting the value of this in the destructor (and constructor).  cout << "\nObject " << this << " under testing is dying! " << endl; -- That would have made much more sense.  Then you would have seen that the objects you are destroying were not being tracked correctly using your current logging.

This statement:
(*chamber).push_back(Testing(true, i));

Creates a temporary Testing object and then pushes a copy of it into the vector.  You are not logging the construction of that copy (because you are not following the Rule of 3/5/0), but you are logging its destruction.
Also, when the vector's internal array needs to be resized beyond its current capacity, a new array has to be created, and the existing elements from the old array are copied/moved to the new array, but you are not logging those constructions, either.
This is why you are seeing more destructor calls than constructor calls.
You need to add logging to the copy and move constructors of the Testing class.  You should also log each object's this pointer instead of (or at least in addition to) its object_id. That will give you a better idea of what is actually going on with the objects:
class Testing{
    
    ...

    public:
        Testing(bool alive, int id);
        Testing(const Testing &src); // <-- add this
        Testing(Testing &&src); // <-- add this
        ~Testing();

        ...
};

Testing::Testing(bool alive, int id) : object_alive{alive}, object_id{id} {
    cout << "\nCONstructor on object: " << this << ", id=" << object_id << endl;
}

Testing::Testing(const Testing &src) : object_alive{src.object_alive}, object_id{src.object_id} {
    cout << "\nCOPY CONstructor on object: " << this << " <- " << &src << ", id=" << object_id << endl;
}

Testing::Testing(Testing &&src) : object_alive{src.object_alive}, object_id{src.object_id} {
    src.object_alive = false;
    src.object_id = 0;
    cout << "\nMOVE CONstructor on object: " << this << " <- " << &src << ", id=" object_id << endl;
}

Testing::~Testing(){
    unalive();
    cout << "\nDEstructor on object: " << this << ", id=" << object_id << endl;
}

In the for loop itself, you can avoid an unnecessary temporary object being copied by using emplace_back() instead of push_back():
(*chamber).emplace_back(true, i);

